# How do I know which App is sending Vibrate-only Notification?

Tags: notifications, iphone, apns

I have an iPhone 5s, iOS 7.1.1, with around 200 Apps installed.

Recently my phone receives some notifications which does not appear in Notification Center, Lock Screen, or Badge Icons. It only vibrates (no sound too).

How do I know which App is triggering this notification?

Answer (score 2):

Go into settings>notification center. Look for any apps that only have sounds, then disable it.